# Select single node

Tags: c#, xpath, xmldocument

From the following xml:

```
<response>
    <content>
        <Result xmlns="http://www.test.com/nav/webservices/types">
            <Name>Test</Name>
        </Result>
    </content>
    <status>ok</status>
</response>
```

I am trying to get the value of the Name element the following way but that does not work:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var response = new XmlDocument();
    response.Load("Response.xml");
    var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(response.NameTable);
    namespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.test.com/nav/webservices/types");

    Console.WriteLine(response.SelectSingleNode("/response/content/Result/Name", namespaceManager).InnerXml);
}
```

How can I select the Name element?

Comment: BTW, in 2016, you should be using `XDocument` and Linq2Xml...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would have worked just fineif the Xml had defined the namespace with a "ns:" prefix.

But in this case, the namespace is given without any prefix, which sets the default namespace for everything in the Result tag to ".../webservice/types".

To reflect this, you need to modify the Xpath, and tell the XmlDocument that the nodes you are looking for under Resultare in the webservice/types namespace. So your query will look like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(response.SelectSingleNode(@"/response/content/ns:Result/ns:Name", namespaceManager).InnerXml);
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting directly the text value of a node there is a `text()` function, if used in the query it would look like:

```
/response/content/Result/Name/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.InnerXml = "<response><content><Result xmlns=\"http://www.test.com/nav/webservices/types\"><Name>Test</Name></Result></content><status>ok</status>";
string elementValue = String.Empty;

if (xmlDoc != null)
{
    xNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Result");
    xNodeList = xNode.ChildNodes;
    foreach (XmlNode node in xNodeList)
    {
        elementValue = node.InnerText;
    }
}
```